# in html, How can i change select-option menu with input html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code works good in form select-option html code.
But form input menu doesn't.
Below is my code.

```
<script>
   function showUser(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
 } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Above is good! but below is my code. why doesn't this work?? 
Input type="submit" doesn't work well, either. 
How can i overcome this problem??

```
 <script>
  same as above...
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  ## Here is wrong, input element.##
      <input type="text" name="users" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)>
 </select>
 </form>
 <br>
 <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

What is something wrong??
Help me!

Comment: what `<input>` inside `<select>` tag? Is it correct?

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow new user. you should accept the answer if you think its what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an end quote

You have

```
onkeyup="showUser(this.value)>
```

Should be:

```
onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
```

You also can't nest an `<input>` inside a `<select>`. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r88E/) and note the `</select>` is in red because it is invalid. The second select in the fiddle is done correctly.

Comment: @acarlon - now get +1